# How to track added tests?

Tags: git, testing, junit, testng

I need to track added tests and show weekly statistics how much tests were added, in which area, etc. I'm using git as source control and JUnit and TestNG as test frameworks. I found that I can use "git whatchanged" and process obtained results but is this optimal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of continuous integration tools report metrics like these except they usually only compare recent changes.  Some might be configurable to go back and compare weeks away etc but I'm not sure.

You can always do it by checking out a revision from today, and also a week ago etc, then running the tests and comparing the number of tests run and the coverage reports.  This should give you the number of new tests and what areas of the code are now covered.